# add badge to tabbar in react native router flux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tabbar, react-native-router-flux

i'm trying to make a home page which contain a tabbar. there are 4 tabs, and 1 of them is inbox tabs, which shows all messages accepted. but on the inbox tabs, I wanted to put a notification showing the number of messages that hasn't been read. can anyone please tell me how to put the notification on tabs?

here is my tabs using router flux :

```
<Scene 
    hideNavBar={true}
    key="hometab" 
    tabs
    tabBarStyle={{backgroundColor: '#1C2219'}}   
    activeTintColor="#FFBD05"
    inactiveTintColor="white">
           <Scene key="tab1home" component={Tab1Home} title="Home" iconName="ios-home" icon={TabIcon} hideNavBar={true}/>
           <Scene key="tab2request"
                  component={Tab2Request}
                  title="Request"
                  iconName="ios-list"
                  icon={TabIcon} />
           <Scene key="tab3inbox"
                  component={Tab3Inbox}
                  title="Inbox"
                  iconName="ios-mail"
                  icon={TabIcon}/>
           <Scene key="tab4profile" 
                  component={Tab4Profile} 
                  title="Profile" 
                  iconName="md-person" 
                  icon={TabIcon} 
                  hideNavBar={true}/>
</Scene>
```

here is my TabIcon.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

export default class TabIcon extends Component {
    render() {
        var color = this.props.selected? '#FFBD05':'white';
        return(
            <View>
                <Icon style={{color: color}} name={this.props.iconName||"circle"} size={40}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```